# How to identify the clicked button from a specific card and pass on a field value from that card to local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a list of cards using for loop and fetching field values. I am using Django and Python.
Each card has certain fields such as ID, Title, Status etc. and each card has a button.
On clicking the button on a specific card, I would like to store the value of a specific field from that card, say ID into local storage so that I can pass it to another HTML page.

How should I do this?

Note:
1)I understand that passing values via local storage may not be the optimal solution, but I would like to solve the above-mentioned problem first.
2)I am new to web development and this is my first Stackoverflow post. :)

```html
<form name="CarsListForm" method="post">
  {% for car in cars.all %}
  <div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <h5 class="card-title"> {{ car.carID }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <h5 class="card-title"> {{ car.carTitle }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="float-right"> {{car.carStatus}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="float-right">{{car.carImage}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6 class="card-text"> {{ car.carID }}</h6>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="card-text"> {{ car.carDescription }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
      <!--<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:20px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Attach docs"></i></button>-->
      <button onclick="addTrip()" class="btn addTrip-btn">
                            Add Trip

                            <!--<i class="fas fa-user-plus" style="font-size:20px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Assign work order"></i>-->
                        </button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br> {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do that would be using javascript as follows

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

However, if your target is just to use the data in next html page, pass it as get request.

```
<a href="{% url 'yournextpage' car.carID %}">Add Trip</a>
```